# Appium + Python selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Method is not implemented

Tags: python-3.x, automated-tests, appium, bdd, python-appium

In my python project I use Appium to prepare automation test for Android operation system. In my project I use Page Object Model + BDD. Below are files which I have.

base_page.py

```
class BasePage:

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver


    def click_element(self, by_locator):
        try:
            element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(by_locator))
            self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
        except EX as e:
            print("Exception! Can't click on the element")


    def get_element_text(self, by_locator):
        element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(by_locator))
        return element.text


    def verify_element_displayed(self, by_locator):
        try:
            element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(by_locator))
            return element.is_displayed()
        except:
            return False
```

access.py

```
class AccessDevice(BasePage):

    text_title = (By.ID, "com.android.permissioncontroller:id/permission_message")
    allow_button = (By.ID, "com.android.permissioncontroller:id/permission_allow_button")
    deny_button = (By.ID, "")

    def __init__(self, driver):
        super().__init__(driver)

    def validate_text_title(self):
        self.verify_element_displayed(self.text_title)
        assert self.get_element_text(self.text_title) == "text to validate"

    def click_allow_button(self):
        self.click_element(self.allow_button)
```

steps.py

```
from behave import *


@step('I should see "Text" dialog')
def validate_text_title(context):
    context.app.access_pictures_videos.validate_text_title()


@step('I click on the "Allow" button')
def click_allow_btn(context):
    context.app.access_pictures_videos.click_allow_button()
```

launch.feature

```
Feature: Launch application

  Scenario: Verify that logo display correctly on the screen
    Given I should see "Text" dialog
    When I click on the "Allow" button
```

After run feature file errors appears on step "I click on the "Allow" button". First step connected to validate text works fine.
No idea how to fix it. Will be grateful for tips guys what I am doing wrong.

This is output with errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Method is not implemented
Stacktrace:
NotImplementedError: Method is not implemented
    at AndroidUiautomator2Driver.execute (/tmp/.mount_Appiumvruux0/resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-android-driver/lib/commands/execute.js:14:11)
    at commandExecutor (/tmp/.mount_Appiumvruux0/resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/basedriver/driver.js:335:9)
    at /tmp/.mount_Appiumvruux0/resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/async-lock/lib/index.js:146:12
    at AsyncLock._promiseTry (/tmp/.mount_Appiumvruux0/resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/async-lock/lib/index.js:280:31)
    at exec (/tmp/.mount_Appiumvruux0/resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/async-lock/lib/index.js:145:9)
    at AsyncLock.acquire (/tmp/.mount_Appiumvruux0/resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/async-lock/lib/index.js:162:3)
    at AndroidUiautomator2Driver.executeCommand (/tmp/.mount_Appiumvruux0/resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/basedriver/driver.js:348:39)
    at AppiumDriver.executeCommand (/tmp/.mount_Appiumvruux0/resources/app/node_modules/appium/lib/appium.js:563:36)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:5)
    at asyncHandler (/tmp/.mount_Appiumvruux0/resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/protocol.js:297:21)
```

Appium: 1.22.0
Python: 3.8.10